# How to stop setInterval in a do while loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, setinterval

I want to do is stop setInterval after the do while loop meet the condition.

My problem is even the while loop condition is meet the setInterval is still running.

```
do
{
setInterval(
Vinformation();
,500);
}while($('#emailCodeResult').val() !='')

function Vinformation(){
   var data = {};
        data.emailCodeResult = $('#emailCodeResult').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Oppa.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function (result) {



        }
     });
            return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var itvl1= window.setInterval(function(){
        Vinformation();
    },500);

    function Vinformation(){
        var data = {};
        data.emailCodeResult = $('#emailCodeResult').val();

        if(data.emailCodeResult  !=''){
            window.clearInterval(itvl1);
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Oppa.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType:"Jenter code hereSON",
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });
        return false;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `while` loop here at all. In combination with `setInterval` it doesn't make sense. What you need is probably just [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval):

```
var interval = setInterval(Vinformation, 500);

function Vinformation() {

    if ($('#emailCodeResult').val() == '') {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }

    var data = {};
    data.emailCodeResult = $('#emailCodeResult').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Oppa.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (result) {
        }
    });
}
```

Use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) function to stop interval.

Also note, that `setInterval` expects function reference as the first argument so this `setInterval(Vinformation(), 500)` is not correct, because you immediately invoke the `Vinformation` function.

Comment: i need a do while loop cuz emailCodeResult value is provided by another ajax.